# How to select Records based on one to many relationship and from one table not in the other?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to `SELECT` the `Top 5` Record from a TableA not in TableB, then JOIN the result on another table, this give me all records related to the top 5. Finally, insert the Reps into *TableB* which prevents them from getting in the next result-set.

To get the top 5, I wrote the following query:

```
WITH DistinctCustomerRep AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 CustomerRepID
FROM MySchema.TableA A 

WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT CustomerRepID FROM MySchema.MyTableB B
WHERE CustomerRepID = A.CustomerRepID)

OR A.ModifiedDate >= DATEADD(SECOND, -30, GETDATE())
OR A.CreatedDate  >= DATEADD(SECOND, -30, GETDATE())
) 
SELECT  * CustomerID, CustomerLName    
FROM MySchema.TableA
```

Next I need to get all of the customers related to the top 5 record I the previous result set. The Objective is to find all of the customers related to the top 5 records above.

I added the following code:

```
SELECT CustomerID, CustomerLName

FROM MySchema.TableA A 

INNER JOIN DistinctCustomerRep B ON A.CustomerRepID = B.CustomerRepID

WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT CustomerRepID FROM MySchema.MyTableB B
WHERE CustomerRepID = A.CustomerRepID) 

OR A.ModifiedDate >= DATEADD(SECOND, -30, GETDATE())
OR A.CreatedDate  >= DATEADD(SECOND, -30, GETDATE())

ORDER BY A.CustomerRepID ASC;
```

The result gives me only 5 Customer Reps, but also return all of the customers related to the 5 reps.

I am having issues with the Update part, the `ModifiedDate Column` and the `CreatedDate Column`. If there is a problem with the query or a slight delay from the server then the 30 second time will prevent any results, since it would have passed. If I make the time too long, the I risk inserting duplicates.

Note: Each time the query is run, the top five reps are then insert into TableB, this allows only new or updated records to get into the next result-set.  For brevity sake, I left out the insert part.

Is there a better alternative that will ensure the records are not reinserted?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understood the entire thing, and the updates/inserts based on something like `A.ModifiedDate >= DATEADD(SECOND, -30, GETDATE())` doesn't seems to be a good idea, but i'll try to give you a quick answer :

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT CustomerRepID FROM MySchema.MyTableB B
                  WHERE CustomerRepID = A.CustomerRepID)

OR (
  ( A.ModifiedDate >= DATEADD(SECOND, -30, GETDATE())
    OR A.CreatedDate  >= DATEADD(SECOND, -30, GETDATE())
   )  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT CustomerRepID FROM MySchema.MyTableB B
                  WHERE CustomerRepID = A.CustomerRepID)
```